# ng-file-upload to S3 with v4 Auth - POST Request Payload not formed properly

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

UPDATE: Fixed by upgrading. Never checked our bower.json, was running with v5.0.9 (now at 12.0.4)! Eating a shoe...

I am attempting a "simple" image upload to S3 using v4 authentication/signing, AngularJS 1.4.1. The v4 stuff seems to be working fine, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the remaining piece when AWS response is telling me I'm not sending the proper request payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message>
  <ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName>
  <ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue>
  <RequestId>B353DC15D1CC165F</RequestId>
  <HostId>8joOZ1eyGCW88X3t6ppL7DSKM8XPIu0MrJ7A/dozNG0Cg205cEH5NeEV1lsvKWw+ama8Xqx1w+s=</HostId>
</Error>
```

In the browser network window the Request payload shows only a single part, where the Upload config object is just there as plain text. This should be multiple parts, one per attribute in the upload object.

[image]

After selecting the file in Chrome, it shows up using

```
<img ngf-src="orgCtrl.logoFileArray[0]">
```

But the same data in the `data` argument to Upload.upload doesn't seem to have the same. My HTML is as follows: one button to select, the other to trigger upload:

```
<button
  ng-show="orgCtrl.editMode"
  class="btn upload-btn"
  ngf-select
  ng-model="orgCtrl.logoFileArray">
  Select
</button>

<button ng-show="orgCtrl.editMode" ng-click="orgCtrl.uploadLogo()">UPLOAD TO S3</button>
```

The Javascript looks like this:

```
view.uploadLogo = function() {

  // (snip) get server-side signature/policy secrets etc

  var uploadObj = {
    url: "https://xyzpdq-test-images.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      "key"                  : "logos/TEST.png",
      "acl"                  : res.s3PolicyResult.acl,
      "policy"               : res.s3PolicyResult.base64Policy,
      "X-amz-credential"     : res.s3PolicyResult.credentials,
      "X-amz-algorithm"      : res.s3PolicyResult.algorithm,
      "X-amz-date"           : res.s3PolicyResult.date,
      "X-amz-signature"      : res.s3PolicyResult.signature,
      "Content-Type"         : 'image/png',
      "success_action_status": res.s3PolicyResult.successStatus,
      "file"                 : view.logoFileArray[0] // ??? no file data?
    }
  };

  $log.debug('uploadObj', uploadObj);

  Upload.upload(uploadObj)
  .then(function (resp) {
    console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
  }, function (resp) {
    console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
  }, function (evt) {
    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
  });
};
```

UPDATE: Per comments, have also tried removing the `Content-Type` element, to no avail: I still see the same JSON object payload instead of multiple parts with boundary markers.

Goal is to make the request look like this (fake signature/policy data, but correct format):

[image]

Do I need *actual form HTML elements* for this? (Trying to get away with just the button with `ngf-select` attrib.) Was able to get the above by using https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/#/1.4.1, but that is using S3 v2 auth. Stopping short of debugging the `ng-file-upload` plugin, but it might come to that.

UPDATE 2:

```
var upload = Upload.upload({
  url: "https://xyzpdq-test-images.s3.amazonaws.com/",
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    key               : "logos/TEST.png",
    acl               : res.s3PolicyResult.acl,
    policy            : res.s3PolicyResult.base64Policy,
    'X-amz-credential': res.s3PolicyResult.credentials,
    'X-amz-algorithm' : res.s3PolicyResult.algorithm,
    'X-amz-signature' : res.s3PolicyResult.signature,
    'Content-Type'    : logoFile.type !== '' ? logoFile.type : 'application/octet-stream',
    filename          : "TEST.png",
    file              : logoFile
  }
});
```

Tried again with that payload, and still the Request Payload is not formatted with each element of the `data` object as a separate part, I'm only seeing a single part with a string representation of `data`:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary6CDiwAgytdoviD7R
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"key":"logos/TEST.png","acl":"public-read","policy":"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAzMC0xMi0zMVQxMjowMDowMC4wMDBaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ImhhdmVuLWRldi1pbWFnZXMifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsImxvZ29zLyJdXX0=","X-amz-credential":"AKIAJAXCR6PRBXGHLU4Q/20160401/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request","X-amz-algorithm":"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256","X-amz-signature":"674d747f7e83375a1742c1a42cfd08799ffed7223aa9a255f4ea5eaad0df4470","Content-Type":"image/png","filename":"TEST.png","file":{}}
------WebKitFormBoundary6CDiwAgytdoviD7R--
```

Comment: The nature of the problem is obvious: you're posting the entire "form" as a json object, so the resulting request body [looks very much different than it should](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html).  I am not sufficiently fluent in JavaScript to tell you how to fix it, but perhaps seeing the documented example will get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: remove the content-type or use Upload.http()

Comment: @danial Thanks, but when I remove Content-Type, I still get the same 400 error and the payload is not being sent multipart/form-data, it's just form-data. If I use Upload.http(), same thing - "Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data". The format is always JSON objects.

Comment: Clarification: the Request Payload is not multipart, it's just the `data: {}` object as text as the only part. What would prevent the request from being formed as a multipart with boundaries?

Comment: Content-Disposition should be form-data. Try the example on the docs: `        key: file.name,
        "Content-Type": file.type != '' ? file.type : 'application/octet-stream', // content type of the file (NotEmpty)
        filename: file.name, 
        file: file`

Comment: @danial thanks again, but I'm still seeing the same result - no multi parts per-element of the `data` object. Just a text blob of the `data` object as the only part.

Comment: multipart is part of the request header and is not needed for each element.